# Skrollr not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, skrollr

so this seems to be a [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=skrollr+mobile), however none of the answers have provided me with any joy. I've fully read the [Skrollr Documentation](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#skrollr-0626) and can conclude I'm totally at a loss here.

[image: My Website]

My basic html markup:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Head Stuff -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="navbar">
      <!-- This is a fixed position div -->
    </div>
    <div id="skrollr-body">
      <!-- Rest of my site -->
    </div>
    <script src="skrollr.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

So you can see as the [documentation states](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#what-you-need-in-order-to-support-mobile-browsers) my fixed element is outside my other content.

---

I'm using **Version 0.6.26 (2014-06-08)** - downloaded from the [GitHub](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) page.

[image: Download Zip]

Mobile testing on iPad 2, iOS7 *and* Google Nexus 4, Android 4.4.4

*Thanks in advance for any suggestions/help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply hadn't styled/set a height on the division `skrollr-body`. I fixed simply by adding:

```
#skrollr-body {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) (about half way down under the section **mobile support**), to make it work on mobile devices you need a `#skrollr-body` on your page, which I did not see in your source.

Also, [this](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/265) github issue seems to address this problem.

Comment: Line 44: <div id="skrollr-body">